# C- Sorting an array of pointers to integers that can be positive or negative

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

For class I need to generate an array of 100 integers between a minimum and a maximum (that works fine right now), and then in a separate function, create an array of pointers and sort it in ascending order.

`int *ptr` is a pointer to the original array and SIZE is defined as 100 in the header

```
void sort(int *ptr){
    int *sortAr[SIZE] = { NULL };
    int i = 0, j, swap;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        sortAr[i] = ptr[i];
    for (i = 0; i < (SIZE - 1); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (sortAr[j] > sortAr[j + 1])
            {
                swap = sortAr[j];
                sortAr[j] = sortAr[j + 1];
                sortAr[j + 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
    int z = 0;
    for (z = 0; z < SIZE; z++)
        printf("%d\t", sortAr[z]);
}
```

The code I'm using works fine when all the integers in the original array are positive or negative, but when there's a mix, it'll sort the array to contain the positive numbers in asc order, then all the negatives in asc order. For example:

```
4       10      12      14      14      16      17      19      20      21
28      33      35      35      36      38      39      41      41      41
45      45      45      47      48      49      50      54      64      66
67      68      70      72      73      73      74      75      75      76
76      77      78      78      79      86      86      87      87      91
92      95      95      98      -100    -99     -92     -86     -86     -84
-82     -80     -78     -78     -76     -73     -73     -71     -70     -70
-69     -64     -63     -63     -58     -56     -53     -50     -49     -48
-44     -42     -36     -32     -30     -25     -24     -24     -21     -20
-20     -19     -17     -17     -10     -6      -5      -4      -3      -3
```

Any ideas on what's up?

Comment: You're doing the selection sort? Shouldn't your nested `for` loops be like this: `for(i = 0; i < (SIZE - 1); i++) for(j = (i + 1); j < SIZE; j++) ...`? See the difference?

Comment: Using an array of pointers to sort an integer array seems a bit odd.   What is the purpose of this requirement?

Comment: What do you think this code does?       for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    sortAr[i] = ptr[i];

Comment: Possibly to leave the original array unsorted?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this code is not doing what you think it is doing.

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        sortAr[i] = ptr[i];

It looks like it is storing the values from the ptr array into the pointer array, rather than the address of that element.

When you compile are their any warnings?

Comment: Consider this: -100 stored as an 8 bit number has the hex value of 0x9C, -99 stored in the same way has the value of 0x9D. Following through, 4 has the hex value of 0x4 and -3 has the hex value of 0xFD - that is to say, the hexadecimal representation _is_ sorted from smallest to largest - the problem is though, that your numbers are signed..

Comment: @EvilTeach: lots of warnings about `warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast`.  Not good.

Comment: `if (sortAr[j] > sortAr[j + 1])` is comparing the pointers, not the integers that they point to.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < (SIZE - 1); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE - i - 1; j++)
        {



u sorting is auwfull. it even not buble(and buble is very bad -and must not used anybody). pls use some other sort algo- for example piromidal

Answer (score 4):

You have passed in an original array of `int`, but you have copied it into an array of `int*`.  When you later compare these, you have *undefined behaviour* because you are not allowed to compare pointers unless they belong to the same memory block from a single allocation.

What is actually happening is that internally the pointer is `unsigned`, so your negative values are becoming large positive values.  As luck would have it, the value is being correctly cast back to an `int` for the `printf` call so it's harder to see that you did something bad (unless you read your compiler's warnings).

Declare your array like this instead:

```
int sortAr[SIZE];
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you copy the array into the array of pointers is wrong. This is the correct way:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    sortAr[i] = &ptr[i];
```

And when you compare the contents of the array of pointers, you should be using this syntax

```
if (*sortAr[j] > *sortAr[j + 1]) { ... }
```

The same goes for when you print the contents

```
for (z = 0; z < SIZE; z++)
    printf("%d\t", *sortAr[z]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You sort an array based on the *values* stored in the array. You can certainly use an array of pointers to *reference* all values in the array, but to sort using the pointer array, you must *dereference* the pointers so you are actually sorting based on the values.

For example, the following creates a random array of 100 values between -100 and 100, assigns an array of pointers to reference the values, and then sorts the values using the pointer array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXI 100

int main (void) {

    int arr[MAXI] = {0};
    int *arrp[MAXI] = {NULL};
    int i, j, swap;

    srand (time (NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < MAXI; i++) {            /* generate random values */
        arr[i] = rand() % (MAXI * 2 + 1) - MAXI; /* -100 < rand < 100 */
        arrp[i] = &arr[i];                  /* assign pointer value   */
    }

    printf ("\noriginal array - by pointers\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < MAXI; i++) {
        if (i && !(i % 10)) putchar ('\n');
        printf (" %4d", *(arrp[i]));
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    for (i = 0; i < MAXI - 1; i++) {        /* sort pointer array */
        for (j = 0; j < MAXI - i - 1; j++) {
            /* For decreasing order use < */
            if (*(arrp[j]) > *(arrp[j + 1])) {
                swap = *(arrp[j]);
                *(arrp[j]) = *(arrp[j + 1]);
                *(arrp[j + 1]) = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    printf ("\nsorted array - by pointers\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < MAXI; i++) {
        if (i && !(i % 10)) putchar ('\n');
        printf (" %4d", *(arrp[i]));
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/bubblesort

original array - by pointers

   55   88   94  -50   64  -64  -23   39   43  -67
  -75   44  -23   64   47  -18  -11  -50   76  -10
   32  -35  -53    9   95    8  -28   53  -39   32
  -88   67  -31  -94  -84  -68   93  -57   21   35
  -74   46  -22  -46    9   76   36   99  -75  -39
  -62    8   26  -65   67  -30   -6  -62  -77    5
   21   86  -29   90   92  -63   73   85  -19   -7
   19  -43  -61   48   11   48   23   97   -4   -2
  -43  -16  -95   33  -30   72  -97   64   61   77
  -32  -69   62  -10  -80    4   27   93  -12   58

sorted array - by pointers

  -97  -95  -94  -88  -84  -80  -77  -75  -75  -74
  -69  -68  -67  -65  -64  -63  -62  -62  -61  -57
  -53  -50  -50  -46  -43  -43  -39  -39  -35  -32
  -31  -30  -30  -29  -28  -23  -23  -22  -19  -18
  -16  -12  -11  -10  -10   -7   -6   -4   -2    4
    5    8    8    9    9   11   19   21   21   23
   26   27   32   32   33   35   36   39   43   44
   46   47   48   48   53   55   58   61   62   64
   64   64   67   67   72   73   76   76   77   85
   86   88   90   92   93   93   94   95   97   99
```

**Sorting Only the Pointers**

If you only want to sort the array of pointers and leave the original array values untouched, that can be done as well by comparing the *dereferenced* values, but then only swapping the pointers:

```
int i, j, *swap;
...
for (i = 0; i < MAXI - 1; i++) {        /* sort pointer array */
    for (j = 0; j < MAXI - i - 1; j++) {
        /* For decreasing order use < */
        if (*(arrp[j]) > *(arrp[j + 1])) { /* compare values */
            swap = arrp[j];                /* swap pointers  */
            arrp[j] = arrp[j + 1];
            arrp[j + 1] = swap;
        }
    }
}

printf ("\nsorted array - by pointers\n\n");
for (i = 0; i < MAXI; i++) {
    if (i && !(i % 10)) putchar ('\n');
    printf (" %4d", *(arrp[i]));
}
putchar ('\n');

printf ("\noriginal array\n\n");
for (i = 0; i < MAXI; i++) {
    if (i && !(i % 10)) putchar ('\n');
    printf (" %4d", arr[i]);
}
putchar ('\n');
```

Printing with the pointers will give the same sorted order, but printing the array values directly, will provide the original unsorted array. e.g.:

```
$ sorted array - by pointers

 -100  -99  -98  -98  -97  -95  -93  -93  -92  -86
  -86  -84  -81  -75  -73  -72  -67  -65  -64  -63
  -62  -59  -55  -53  -53  -52  -50  -48  -46  -42
  -40  -40  -37  -32  -31  -31  -28  -28  -27  -23
  -21  -20  -20  -17  -11   -9   -8   -6   -4   -4
   -1   -1    0    2    6   18   21   22   22   23
   24   26   26   28   29   33   34   34   34   36
   39   42   43   43   52   58   58   61   62   65
   67   70   70   73   79   80   80   80   80   81
   82   89   89   90   92   92   94   97   98  100

original array

   80  -99   21  -98  -63  -52  -59  -73  -75    2
  -62  -53  -31   92  -31  -98  -32   36  -27  -28
  -21   22   -6  -53   92   29  100   97  -40  -86
  -64   90  -84   58   43  -97  -95   34   81   82
  -65  -81   79  -46   61   98  -93  -72  -17  -20
    0   62   52   94  -92   43   22   58  -11   33
   73   26  -28   89  -67  -86   42   89   -1   23
   70   34   -8   -1   39  -48   -4   -4  -20   80
   26   80   -9  -23   24  -50   70  -55  -93  -42
   28   80   34 -100   18   67   65  -40    6  -37
```

**You Must Pass Array-of-Pointers to Sort by Pointer in Function**

Another issue with your function is you are passing a pointer (an array of int), but in order to sort by array of pointers, you must pass an array of pointers to the sort function (e.g. pointer-to-pointer-to-int). To sort only the pointer array in a function while leaving the original array unchanged, you could use the following:

```
/* sort an array of 'n' pointers to int in 'a' */
void psort (int **a, int n)
{
    int i, j, *swap;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {        /* sort pointer array */
        for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            /* For decreasing order use < */
            if (*(a[j]) > *(a[j + 1])) { /* compare values     */
                swap = a[j];             /* swap only pointers */
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the example above, you would replace the sort in `main()` with:

```
psort (arrp, MAXI);
```

Which would result in the same results posted above for the sort only pointer case.